# Validation logic for adjacent checkboxes

Tags: .net, wpf, algorithm, mvvm, checkbox

guys!

I have something like that:

[image: 4 Combobox]

I need to write some validation logic. The main rule - user can select only adjacent checkboxes. For example 1;2;3 or 2;3 or 3;4 and etc. (don't choose 1;3 or 1;2;4 and etc(without gaps)).
And I have no idea,how can I implement that algorithm simply.

I Use MVVM approach and this is part of my ViewModel class(short):

```
public bool FirstIsCheck {get;set;}
public bool SecondIsCheck {get;set;}
public bool ThirdIsCheck {get;set;}
public bool FourthIsCheck {get;set;}
```

Comment: Make the checked values a bool array, then check whether all values are false or whether there is a neighbouring true value in a loop. There is a UI nightmare lurking here: How does the user know she can only check adjacent boxes? So you should use the logic above to grey out non-adjacent checkboxes when checking a box. This should rule out checking invalid checkboxes - and make the logic clear to the user.

Comment: Idea of loop seems interesting.
And this control will be used by a special user, who must to know this rule(but may do mistake)

Comment: The user can select only one `CheckBox` or must necessarily be `>= 2`?

Comment: from 1 to 4 (0 default)

Comment: This is equivalent to selecting a range - for which two combo-boxes (from/to) might be a better interface.

Comment: You might also consider to ensure that only adjacent checkboxes are checked by automatically checking and unchecking other checkboxes when a checkbox is clicked by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for good ideas, especially about "range".
I like 2 combobox(from/to) variant, and after them i had seen on slider control with 2 thumbs(f.e. RangeSlider in http://avaloncontrolslib.codeplex.com/ )

But in my solution I will use another approach(Only because i have 4 elements):
User select some checkboxes(correct or incorrect) and after that(when he try to save changes, f.e.) he may to see error message.
IsChecked values will be added in a collection and we find Max of Min values + check them.
(in that example i use string to save final result)

```
        string temp = "";
        List<int> range = new List<int>();
        if (FirstIsCheck) { temp += 1 + ";"; range.Add(1); }
        if (SecondIsCheck) { temp += 2 + ";"; range.Add(2); }
        if (ThirdIsCheck) { temp += 3 + ";"; range.Add(3); }
        if (FourthIsCheck) { temp += 4 + ";"; range.Add(4); }

        Result = temp;

        if(range.Count>1)
        {
            var max = range.Max();
            var min = range.Min();

            if (max - min == 2 && range.Count != 3) throw new Exception();
            if (max - min == 3 && range.Count != 4) throw new Exception();
        }
```

In my case it works, but if you have more elements that approach will be ugly. (and you must think about use some slider controls, or  2 combobox/TextBox from-to fields)